# Cleaning up x-axis because there are too many datapoints

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

I have a data set that is like this

```
Date      Time        Cash
1/1/20    12:00pm     2
1/1/20    12:02pm     15
1/1/20    12:03pm     20 
1/1/20    15:06pm     30
2/1/20    11:28am     5
 .         .          
 .         .          
 .         .          
3/1/20    15:00pm     3
```

I basically grouped all the data by date along the y-axis and time along the x-axis, and plotted a facetgrid as shown below:

```
df_new= df[:300]

g = sns.FacetGrid(df_new.groupby(['Date','Time']).Cash.sum().reset_index(), col="Date", col_wrap=3)
g = g.map(plt.plot, "Time", "Cash", marker=".")
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
```

What I got back was hideous(as shown below). So I'm wondering is there anyway to tidy up the x-axis? Maybe like having 5-10 time data labels so the time can be visible, or maybe expanding the image?

[image]

Edit: I am plotting using seaborn. I will want it to look something like that below where the x-axis has only a couple of labels:

[image]

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Convert your date strings to datetime.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use moving average instead of the actual data? You can count the moving average of any data with the following function:

```
def moving_average(a, n=10) :
    ret = np.cumsum(a, dtype=float)
    ret[n:] = ret[n:] - ret[:-n]
    return ret[n - 1:] / n
```

Set `n` to average you need, you can play around with that value. `a` is in your case variable `Cash` represented as numpy array.

After that, set column `Cash` to the moving average count from real values and plot it. The plot curve will be smoother.

P.S. the plot of suicides you have added in edit is really unreadable, as the range for y axis is way higher than needed. In practice, try to avoid such plots.

**Edit**
I did not notice how you aggregate the data at first, you might want to work with date and time merged. I do not know where you load data from, in case you load it from csv you can add this to `read_csv` method: `parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']]`. In case not, you can play around with the dataframe:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])
```

you create a new column with datetime and can work simply with that.

Comment: hi there, nope I've not tried it, but I will give it a shot. Im also looking at the x-axis to have lesser labels :) thanks for your inputs!

Comment: @Jonathan let me know if you resolved the problem, consider accepting the answer if so :)

Comment: @Jonathan +added an edit since I didnt notice you work with date and time separately at first